# How make a "SELECT LIKE" in arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays

i want to know if there is any way to return objects in array if i pass only some letters. For example:

```
 const people = [
  {
    name: "Denis",
    lastname: Sckt,
  },
  {
    name: "Denilson",
    lastname: Rower,
  },
  {
    name: "Daniela",
    lastname: Roks,
  },
];
```

so i want to make a "filter" like i can do in SQL. When i type "D" it returns "Denis", "Denilson", "Daniela".

So if i type "De" it will only return "Denis" "Denilson".

And if i type "Da" it will only return "Daniela"

im sorry if the way i asked this question is a little bit confuse. basically i just to make a "SELECT LIKE %" in this arrays. Thank you for your time !

Comment: Have a look at using select2: https://select2.org/

Comment: assuming you have a variable `searh`,  `people.filter(x => x.name.indexOf(searh) === 0)`

Comment: Thank you R Pasha for you answer !